# Magento 2, minicart, change "Go to Checkout" text to "Checkout" only

Tags: magento2, overrides

I have been trying to change `Go to Checkout` text to `Checkout` in mini cart in Magento 2.
I have new theme applied and placed override file as follows:

```
 app/design/frontend/Darkmage/newtheme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/content.html
```

Whatever I change the texts  (only) like `Go to Checkout`, `View and edit cart`, it is not reflecting in minicart, though i clean, flush cache.

Comment: check here this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/245215/rename-shipping-address-into-delivery-address-magento2-checkout-page/245243#245243)

Answer (score 0):

Your file location is wrong. Instead of mentioned path, use below path

```
app/design/frontend/Darkmage/newtheme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html
```

You forgot `minicart` directory.

Clear cache of Magento and clear cache of browser. After clearing cache, your minicart will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Strings added in `.phtml` templates that are wrapped up in the `__('<string>')` method can be translated using `.csv` file. This is better practise and would recommend using this method rather than editing the string directly in the `.phtml` template file.

You can use the **i18n (internationalization) tool** to generate the en_US dictionary for your custom theme. Run following command:

```
php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases --output="app/design/frontend/CustomVendor/CustomTheme/i18n/en_US.csv" app/design/frontend/CustomVendor/CustomTheme
```

Now, open the newly generated `app/design/frontend/CustomVendor/CustomTheme/i18n/en_US.csv` file and add your translation in following format:

> "OriginalText1", "Translation1"
>
> "OriginalText2", "Translation2"
>
> "OriginalText3", "Translation3"

Now you need to run  the deploy command to get changes of localization: Use following command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below path -

```
app/design/frontend/Themename/core/i18n/en_US.csv
```

check with `"GO TO CHECKOUT","GO TO CHECKOUT"`